# Email template subject not populating

Tags: apex, email, email-template

I have a web service class which is called from a quote button,  and I'm passing the quote Id to the class. I am creating a single email message object and I'm setting an email template for it, but the subject which has the 'Quote number', is not getting populated. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Can you please help me out.

EDIT:
subject : Project Archive Quote - {!Quote.QuoteNumber}
I am using the quote object, but the merge fields on the quote object wont come without the setWhatId attribute, but the setWhatId attribute is only for a certain set of standard objects and not for quote. That is the issue.

Comment: Please add the template "Subject" string and the code that creates the Messaging.SingleEmailMessage to the question.

Comment: @KeithC Edited the subject. I get this error "INVALID_ID_FIELD, Only accounts, assets, campaigns, cases, contracts, opportunities, orders, products, solutions and custom objects are allowed as whatId."